# Querying a document from array inside a collection mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mongodb-query

I'm trying to fetch a data from my MongoDB's collection, I have the following structure:

[check JSON structure here.](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=68b21c5870cc410b8e121012eab5315f)

So basically the thing I want to do for example is to target object with `id: 456` FROM `events` where the top level `_id` is == 2 and to return only that object.

I've tried `aggregate()` , `findOne()` but none of them works the way I want... any help will be appreciated.

Examples I've tried:

`db.collectionName.findOne({ _id: '2', events: { $elemMatch: { _id: 456 } }})`

I can't change the following structure , because the top level _id is actually userId and I want to fetch all the events for the user with _id: '2' for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with filtering by `_id` to filter out as much as possible. Then you can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to get single event per document and apply another match for nested `_id`. In the last step you can use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to get only nested document, try:

```
Model.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: "2" } },
    { $unwind: "$events" },
    { $match: { "events._id": "456" } },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$events" } } 
])
```

Outputs:

```
{ "_id" : "456", "name" : "eventName_1" }
```

Comment: Hm.. It partially works. For Example on the second $match, If I write like.. 
 { $match: { 'events.eventName: '123' }} , it returns me the object, but if I try with {$match : { 'events._id' : '456'} } doesn't return nothing :\ , may that be because I'm using '_id' instead of 'id' for example?

Comment: I think my problem comes from there, that I'm creating the event id with MongoDB ObjectId(); so in the database , the 'id' is represented as '_id' : ObjectId('id'); and not only '_id': 'id'

Comment: Yeah I can confirm that , saving the event `id` as ObjectId().toString(); , and then querying it as 'event._id' : eventId works like a charm! Thanks a lot.